# Communication between Java Swing Application(On client side) and server

Tags: java, swing, jsp, jdbc

What are the possible ways in which Java Swing Application which is running on client side can communicate with server?
I've read that JSP can be used in web pages to communicate between server and client.But, is it possible to use JSP with Swing application? if so, how? It would be helpful, if it is demonstrated with simple login form. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have an understanding of what a JSP is.  I suggest reading up on Java Server Pages.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages

Comment: You can implement your own byte protocol to provide such communication. Read about java sockets. 
There are also popular frameworks which could help. For example netty http://netty.io/

Comment: Standard way for this type of communication is to use [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/index-jsp-136424.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any client-side application, whether it be a java swing app or otherwise, can certainly communicate with any server (assuming no network limiting architecture -- firewalls and whatnot). Your options are numerous

- Raw sockets
- Any one of the myriad of network protocols.

  - HTTP/HTTPS
  - FTP
  - SCP
  - et. al.

It depends on what protocol, services and applications are available on the server to connect with.

HTTP/HTTPS is very common.  You'll need to manually create HTTP requests and send them to the server (assuming the server is a web server).

Comment: You've forget the Java standard: RMI

Comment: I didn't forget about it.  "et. al." is latin shorthand for "and others."  I really don't feel like listing every protocol.